# How can i go to USA with F4 category application?

Tags: usa, visa, family

My family applied for US visa through my maternal uncle who lived in New York. We filed in 2006 for the F4 category when I was only 16 years old but I have now turn 29. I am not married.

Now the NVC has asked us to submitt our legal paper for processing but I heared that there is a age limit for getting US visa for the dependent.

Is there any way for me to come with my parents?

Comment: when was the I-130 approved?

Comment: February 13, 2006.

Comment: and when was the I-130 filed? I though you said the I-130 was filed in 2006, so was the I-130 approved in only a month?

Comment: Actuallyi want to say  Filed date means received/approved date.   Maybe the filed date was november 2005 i can't remember the exact date if it's mandatory then i have to know from my uncle ( you may consider it by my assumption)    . Is there any relation between filing date  and age limit.

Comment: The date it was filed should be listed as the "priority date" on the receipt and approval notice. The date it was approved should be the date on the approval notice. Both of these dates are important because the difference between these 2 dates determines how long after you turn 21 before you age out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Main Applicant’s children are aged out or not?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17882/main-applicant-s-children-are-aged-out-or-not)

Comment: I am not clear sir.  we received I-797. Is there any fruitful news by this documents & that shows a received date which i mentioned before. Now they   (CEAC) asked us to pay all fee & affidavit document with financial documents. But i don't understand that should i do this or not?

Comment: @Irreversible, Unfortunately, I think you marriage ended any possibility of you still qualifying for this visa. See the duplicate mention by David earlier.

Comment: @outflak Where's the info that the OP is now married? In the question, the OP says unmarried.